# LaTeX not rendering all test inside HTML file

Tags: php, html, deployment, latex, rendering

I've created a lists of exercises, everyone with the solution, written in a  tag.

```
<?php 
for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){
    $list = '<label class="list-group-item d-flex gap-2">';
    $list .= '<input class="form-check-input flex-shrink-0" type="checkbox" value=""><span>';
    $list .= '$$\int{x^{' . $i . '}+' . $i . '}dx$$';
    $list .= '<small class="d-block text-muted">$\frac{x^{' . $i+1 . '}}{' . $i+1 . '}+' . $i . ' \cdot x$</small></span></label>';
    echo $list;
}?>
```

The code works perfectly but the rendering. The exercise is printed correctly, while the solution is written as latex code, not rendered (By solution i mean the things written in `<small>` tag).
This is the code i use to render LaTeX:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

I think that the problem is because of the usage of the  tag, but i don't know hot to fix it

Comment: Try `' . ($i+1) . '`  or `' . ++$i . '`  instead of `' . $i+1 . '`. Your current syntax works only in php>=8.

Comment: Tried with every method, no one worked :(

Comment: Test here your html output https://jsbin.com/fuvazureyi/edit?html,output I'm not very into latex. Maybe you have to use both times `$$` and not `$`

Comment: Strangely it works. But the rendering with the double dollar give it emphasis, i want the solution to be in single dollar too

Comment: But you can now see that it is more an latex issue than an php issue and is not related to `usage of the tag` or else.  :-)